# Why might long telomeres be selected for in laboratory mice?

Tags: evolution, cancer, natural-selection, senescence, telomere

In a recent episode of [The Portal](https://youtu.be/JLb5hZLw44s), Eric Weinstein sits down with his brother Bret Weinstein to discuss Bret's [Reserve-Capacity Hypothesis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0531556502000128). It's an incredible story of scientific discovery and academic injustice.

One prediction of the hypothesis was that laboratory mice, known at the time to have abnormally long telomeres for their lifespan, were not a representative sample of the wild mouse population because the environment the lab mice were being bred in was selecting for longer telomeres. This had serious implications for drug safety testing.

My surface level understanding as a non-biologist from listening to the Podcast goes like this. Please point out any misunderstandings.

## Antagonistic Pleiotropy Hypothesis for Senescence

George Williams predicted that pleiotropic (multi-purpose) genes which are advantageous early in life but detrimental later in life will be selected for in nature since organisms often die or reproduce long before the disadvantageous effects manifest themselves. This is an evolutionary theory for aging, which argues that trade-offs exist between early life and later life fitness. This effect was observed, but no gene had been known to be the cause. This was the "missing pleiotropy".

## The Hayflick Limit

Telomeres are repeating, non-coding regions of DNA at the end of each chromosome which aid in cell division. Each division, the telomeres shorten. Telomeres are counters of sorts, which provide a hard limit (the Hayflick limit) to the number of divisions a cell can undergo. Any cell that started dividing uncontrollably (cancer) would eventually reach its Hayflick limit and die. Aging (senescence) is the manifestation of cells in an organism reaching their Hayflick limit.

## The Reserve-Capacity Hypothesis

This is Bret Weinstein's work. The way I understand it is that Weinstein pointed out that the missing pleiotropy was not a gene at all, but telomeres. Weinstein observed that there existed a trade-off which was reflected in telomere length. Long telomeres allow cells to repair themselves many more times, slowing the effects of aging, but simultaneously leave the organism vulnerable to cancer, as cells which begin to divide uncontrollably will never reach their Hayflick limit. The length of telomeres is the result of a trade-off between dying of cancer, or dying of old age.

## The JAX Lab Scandal

One critical prediction of the Reserve-Capacity Hypothesis was that mice (which were at the time thought to have abnormally long telomeres for their lifespan) don't naturally have long telomeres. Instead, it was specifically the mice coming from the Jackson (JAX) Laboratory (which supplied a significant percentage of North America with mice) which had abnormally long telomeres. Since JAX Lab had economic incentive to breed as many mice as possible as quickly as possible, they were artificially introducing selective pressures on the mice. Namely, the pressure of breeding the mice early in their lives. This meant that any late-life disadvantages, such as susceptibility to cancer as a result of longer telomeres, were not playing an important role since the mice were bred well before they were likely to develop cancer. Since telomeres are a non-coding region of the chromosome, variation can happen very rapidly (no need for the traditional timescales of Darwinian selection). Over time, long telomeres became dominant in the mice population, and so research being done on mice purchased from JAX lab concluded that mice had very long telomeres.

The primary gap in my understanding is the following. Why was it that longer telomeres were selected for? It is unclear to me how discounting the late-life disadvantages of long telomeres would result in long telomeres becoming dominant in the population. If anything, telomere length should become irrelevant. If so, we'd see a wide distribution of telomere length. That is, unless longer telomeres provide benefits to organisms early in life. Is that the case? If not, how can we explain long telomeres becoming not just common, but dominant?

Comment: That is a very good and well-stated question, outside my knowledge set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their arguments for increased telomere length in lab mice are:

1. Rate of tumour formation is dependent on the number of cells within an organism. Additionally, tumours take time to form. Therefore, small animals that only need to reproduce early in life, like lab mice, are less prone to tumours and there is then less selective pressure favouring telomere shortening.
2. Senescence has a negative effect on reproductive success, even early in life, and there is therefore selective pressure favouring increased telomere length that reduces senescence.
3. While the lack of selection on senescence due to the short window for reproduction could have the opposite effect of reducing telomere length, point 2 is the dominant factor.

To be frank, this all sounds extremely speculative to me and the supporting evidence they did provide was not entirely convincing (though I am far from an expert in the field). Keep in mind that it’s a hypothesis only.

In case you don’t have access to their article, I quoted the relevant section below:

> The unusual telomere system of lab mice may be an unintended consequence of captive breeding. Retirement of breeders after 8 months eliminates selection on late-life effects. Tumor-forming mutations take time to occur, tumors take time to become lethal, and the likelihood of tumor initiation is presumably a function of the number of cells in the body, so in small bodied animals like mice, tumors may be rare and inflict minimal cost in the first eight months of life, even absent a telomeric fail-safe. Further, selection for sustained high reproductive output (beginning early and maintained for 8 months) should strongly favor a reduction in senescent effects occurring in that window. Selection acting to eliminate senescent effects and increase early reproductive output may tend to elongate telomeres. Because of the inextricable connection between tumor suppression and somatic maintenance, telomere elongation should dramatically increase the risk of eventual tumor formation, but any effects manifesting after the breeding cut-off will be selectively irrelevant. By our model, selection for early high rates of reproduction in the absence of selection for longevity or tumor suppression should produce long telomeres and a strong propensity for eventual tumor incidence. Despite diminished senescence, we expect these mice to have reduced maximum longevity compared to wild conspecifics. At all ages, lab mice (with elongated telomeres) should be more likely to die of tumors than wild mice. These mice should also be unusually resilient to somatic damage and show few signs of aging other than tumor formation.
>
> ...
>
> The hypothesis that an 8 month breeding cut-off should select for non-senescent, tumor prone mice seems paradoxical. One might expect the elimination of selection on late life effects to accelerate senescence, not retard it. But in lab mice, selection for high, sustained rates of breeding appears to be the dominant factor. The tumor fail-safe has effectively been turned off, condemning these animals to form tumors, but leaving an early-life window of reproduction within which there is minimal senescent decline.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of follow up questions: How does senescence negatively effect reproductive success early in life? How might the elimination of selection on late life effects accelerate senescence, assuming no other factors were at play?

Comment: @aRockStr (1) This may warrant a separate question, or a better answer to this question. Either way, I don’t have a good answer. Check out [this paper](https://joe.bioscientifica.com/view/journals/joe/230/2/R59.xml) and specifically the section titled *“Cellular senescence and ovarian aging”*; it might give some insight. (2) I think their idea is that without selection on late life effects, selection against tumour formation would be dominant and therefore favour shorter telomeres, which would accelerate senescence.

Comment: (2) is the argument that if aging is a non-issue, the telomere trade-off is dominated by tumour defense?

Comment: Yes that’s my understanding of it.

Comment: I think I understand then. The whole argument relies on the existence of a trade-off between defence against cancer and 'defence' against aging. If one of these factors are removed from the system, the other will dominate. This was Bret Weinstein's contribution.